# Create Devise User from Admin Namespace in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an `admin` namespaced route for a custom dashboard in my app.  I have at least 8 models working, with error free crud operations--all except one. I am using the [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user management and a User model.  I have the `User` model in the admin namespace and the only operation I can get to work is changing role and destroy, but I can't create a new user from the dashboard.  When I try to create a new user; I get the error "You are already signed in.".

**controllers/admin/users_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :admin_only, :except => :show

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user.admin?
      unless @user == current_user
        redirect_to root_path, :alert => 'Access denied.'
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => 'User updated.'
    else
      redirect_to admin_users_path, :alert => 'Unable to update user.'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.destroy
    redirect_to admin_users_path, :notice => 'User deleted.'
  end

  private

  def admin_only
    unless current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path, :alert => 'Access denied.'
    end
  end

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit!
  end

end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:user, :admin]

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**views/admin/users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br/>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div class="from-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 1em">
    <%= f.submit 'Sign up', class: 'btn btn--primary type--uppercase inner-link'  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**views/admin/users/new.html.erb (other method)**

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f| %>
```

*This is how all my name spaced forms are setup but this gives me the error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`*

**routes.rb**

```
...
namespace :admin do
  get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
  resources :pages
  resources :articles
  resources :categories
  resources :tags
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :albums
  resources :banners

  resources :products do
    resources :variations
  end
end
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `registration#create` action is the appropriate architecture for this?

Because that action is built on a different concept, that the user is not logged in and there are a series of checks for that.

`views/admin/users/new.html.erb`

you are using [`registration#new`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L9) controller action, which does not have the `@admin` valorized.

```
def new
   @admin = Admin.find(params[:admin_id])
   ....
end
```

That is why you get the error, also this approach is not correct.
User will need to register with the traditional devise router, then you will also have to create a nested router for admins to create new users.

this is your link to the admin user `registration#new`
Your current view/controller#action has the `@admin = Admin.find(params[:id])` valorized and the view has the following link

```
link_to new_admin_user_path(:admin, :user)
```

the `new_admin_user_path` is for url `/admin/:admin_id/users/sign_up(.:format)` that you define in your nested routes.

**Step 2)** decide which `controller#action` to use

Do you want to use the standard `users/registrations#create` or use a new action for this?

I believe you should enhance `users/registrations#create` by generating the controllers actions in your app as described in [devise guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

then in devise controller `registrations`

```
def new 
   @admin = Admin.new(:params[:admin_id]) if params[:admin_id].present?
end
```

your `registrations#new` and `#create` will still trigger errors, you will have to read how devise creates this users by reading their [amazing sourcecode](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L9) and [rdoc documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_in-instance_method), modify the process accordingly so that `admins` can create `users` by using that `action` otherwise the less `DRY` alternative is creating a new `controller#action` and using it to call an existing `User` method or a method you will create in the `User` model to create users. In the end it a `User` is just an entry in your `users` database table. Just creating in a similar fashion to other users. As the admin is creating the temporary password, encryption/security issues are not anymore that important. The `User` will have to change the password anyway.